# Python test string in list of string format

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I'm looking for a python module that would help to test if a string is in a list of formatted string. I can't find the exact words to explain my problem (that's probably why I didn't find anything) so here is an example :

```
REGISTERED_KEYS = (
    'super_key',
    'key_ending_with_anything_*',
    'anything'
)

is_key_registered("super_key", REGISTERED_KEYS)
>> True

is_key_registered("wrong_key", REGISTERED_KEYS)
>> False

is_key_registered("key_ending_with_anything_foobar", REGISTERED_KEYS)
>> True
```

The thing is not to simply check if a string is in a list but it's also to allow string formatting. I may have to use regexp but I wanted to know if there's an existing module that does this (as it seems to be a common need). 
Edit : the format of my REGISTERED_KEYS doesn't have to me the one I've written. Can be regex.

Thanks

Comment: This is the exact use case of regexes, so the only module you need is `re`

Comment: @lejlot: `'key_ending_with_anything_*'` is not a regex

Comment: it is a regex, it does not matter what kind of syntax you use, * or typical regexes.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use file wildcards, then use the appropriate library for matching filenames: [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)

```
import fnmatch

def is_key_registered(foo, keys):
    return any(fnmatch.fnmatch(foo, key) for key in keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can browse all key an check them:

```
import re


def is_key_registered(key, keys):
    for _ in keys:
        if re.search(_, key):
            return True
```